# session.isOpen() vs session.isConnected()

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on sample of Hibernate4 with Spring 3.1.

In my sample , While i print `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen()` on console it prints

> true

But I am facing an exception on

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected()
```

Exception is:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: isConnected is not valid without active transaction
```

**EDIT :** I googled more and found following solution

`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isConnected()`

But i don't want to write begin transaction maually every time i opearte with session methods like `isConnected`, `get`,`find` , `save` etc.

1. What are the other possible solutions for above exception?
2. What if i place `@Transactional` on my dao class methods?

Regards,

Arun Kumar

Comment: @bbaja42 :  Goal is too simple that using `isConnected()` to verify if the session is currently connected, as it shows in `isOpen()` in order to show the current session in opened or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isConnected is rarely used and for normal DAO methods it is not needed. Get/Find/Save will open a Connection and Transaction if needed behind the scene, nothing you have to take care of manually.